# Wordpress Admin - required custom meta check

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I'm adding custom user meta in wordpress admin, and I would like my two custom fields are required, but how I show error and tell wordpress to not update profile if error ?

```
add_action('personal_options_update', 'sweety_admin_update_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'sweety_admin_update_extra_profile_fields');
function sweety_admin_update_extra_profile_fields($user)
{
    $error = false;

    if (is_super_admin())
    {
            if (!$_POST['country'] || !$_POST['timezone'])
            {
                $error = true;
            }
        update_user_meta($user, 'country_id', $_POST['country']);
        update_user_meta($user, 'timezone_string', $_POST['timezone']);
    }
}
```

Comment: If $error is true, I want to show error message on top of page like "Please select a country in the list..." and update profile only if no error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can try this

```
add_action('user_profile_update_errors', 'validate_extra' 10, 3);
function validate_extra(&$errors, $update = null, &$user  = null)
{
    if (is_super_admin())
    {
        if (!$_POST['country'] || !$_POST['timezone'])
        {
            $errors->add('empty_country', "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please select a country in the list");
        }   
        
    }
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
function save_extra_profile_fields($user)
{
    if (is_super_admin())
    {
        update_user_meta($user, 'country', $_POST['country']);
        update_user_meta($user, 'timezone_string', $_POST['timezone']);
    }
}
```

Comment: notice, to have access to $update and $user on 'validate_extra' function, the hook must look like this: `add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'validate_extra', 10, 3 );`

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it.