# wordpress - is there a built-in function to display validation errors for options pages?

Tags: wordpress

I'm building an admin options page for my plugin and using `register_settings` to setup my validation function. All working fine, but would like a function to define and display an error message in the case of field validation failing. Is there a built-in function in Wordpress and if not, what's the recommended method for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use `add_settings_error()`, documentation at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has its own error manager, it's very simple. To add an error message, at first you have to instantiate your own instance of WP_Error.

```
$myErrors = new WP_Error();
```

The next step is to add your error message

```
$myErrors->add('required', __('Please fill up all the fields correctly !'));
```

Finally you can get your error messages by their error code as follows

```
$msg = $myErrors->get_error_message('required');
```

If you echo `$msg` then it'll print `Please fill up all the fields correctly !`.

Or you can use it as follows

```
if(!isset($_POST['myRequiredField']))
{
    $myErrors=new WP_Error('required', __('Please fill up all the fields correctly !'));
}
```

Then retrieve the error message to print anywhere as follows

```
if (is_wp_error($myErrors)) echo $myErrors->get_error_message();
```

**Reference:** [**Codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) and another answer on [**SO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945757/wordpress-admin-required-custom-meta-check/9946829#9946829) which may give you more ideas.

Comment: I'm using `add_settings_field()` which does the work of insering the field into the form on my plugin options page. How do I get `WP_Error()` involved with that If I have to manually echo the error message?

Comment: Without any code I can't tell anything but you may find [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/how-should-one-implement-add-settings-error-on-custom-menu-pages) helpful.

Comment: You are welcome and don't forget to post the solution here for future reference. :-)